# Does it make sense to close JsonGenerator if it was created on top of ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, json, glassfish

Suppose I want to create JSON and store it in String using Java JSON Streaming API. For that purpose I create ByteArrayOutputStream (BAOS) and JsonGenerator on top of it.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream collector = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = Json.createGenerator(collector);
```

After a while, when I'm done with it, I take String from BAOS and supposed to release all resources. As follows from BAOS *close* method implementation

```
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

it does nothing. *close* method of JsonGenerator, however, not only closes underlying stream, but also flushes buffer and recycles a buffer pool (frankly speaking, I have no idea of what latter means).
I doubt that JsonGenerator buffers data when writes it to BAOS. But, it will take some time from me to investigate it further, so I hope someone already knows: does it make sense to close generator, or doesn't.
**Note**
I use Glassfish implementation of javax.json.

Comment: Before being a `ByteArrayOutputStream` it is an `OutputStream`, and an `OutputStream` should be `close()`d, so just do it. The fact that you identified the output stream as being a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is of no consequence.

Comment: If you will check javadoc of BAOS, you will find, that invocation of close method on it does make nothing by contract.

Comment: I know that; but if ever one day you don't have a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you're screwed --> close all the time, you don't lose anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I checked JsonGeneratorImpl source code. And I have to say that I really need to close it. First of all, JsonGeneratorImpl receives buffer from BufferPoolImpl here:

```
public final char[] take() {
    char[] t = (char[])getQueue().poll();
    if (t == null)
        return new char[4096];
    return t;
}
```

And when we call *close* we put it back:

```
public final void recycle(char[] t)
{
    getQueue().offer(t);
}
```

It doesn't make a lot sense if you create jsonGenerator like I do in question:

```
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = Json.createGenerator(collector);
```

Because in that case, each newly created generator will use its own instance of JsonProvider, and its own instance of buffer pool which will be collected by GC when I'll finish to work with generator. So its better to create JsonGeneratorFactory, because all generators created by this factory will share common buffer pool. And yes — in that case it's really better to close generator at the end.
Another reason to close generator is that *close* method invokes *flushBuffer* method. And yes, generator uses buffer regardless of output stream type:

```
void writeChar(char c) {
    if (this.len >= this.buf.length) {
        flushBuffer();
    }
    this.buf[(this.len++)] = c;
}
```

So the final answer is **yes**. It always makes sense to close JsonGenerator in the end.
**UPDATE**
As @StephenC rightfully noted, there is another reason to close it, because it enforces check for not finished JSON:

```
if ((this.currentContext.scope != Scope.IN_NONE) || (this.currentContext.first)) {
  throw new JsonGenerationException(JsonMessages.GENERATOR_INCOMPLETE_JSON());
}
```

Comment: There is another reason.  Irrespective of the implementation, if you don't call `close()` then the check for incomplete JSON (i.e. not enough "end" calls) won't be done.

Comment: @StephenC, haven't thought about it. Nice addition.

Answer (score 2):

I think always makes sense to close resources when they are done, regardless of the underlying implementation. Nothing says that the implementation won't change in the future, which might then cause resource leaks if they are not handled properly.

If you are using Java 7 or later, both classes implement [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html). Why not just put them in a try-with-resources?

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream collector = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = Json.createGenerator(collector)) {
    // your implementation here  
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exceptions
}
```

No need for the pre Java 7 boilerplate code, and you can be sure that all resources are properly closed.